# Chef deployed Puma server with a Sidekiq worker fails with incorrect ruby version error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra, sidekiq, puma

This rails app's puma/runit service has been working up until I tried to deploy the Sidekiq 3.5.3 gem with my app via chef

In my recipe I've installed 2.0.0p576 via ruby_build recipe

```
which ruby  #gives me /usr/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby -v #return 2.0.0p576
```

templates/default/sv-myapp-run.erb

```
echo "$(ruby -e 'print RUBY_VERSION')" >> check_ruby.txt #returns 2.0.0
exec chpst -u root:root bundle exec puma --config config/puma.rb
```

Inside the log of the runit service I get this message below

```
2015-11-04_06:23:50.99541 /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-3.5.3/lib/sidekiq.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': Sidekiq 3.5.3 does not support Ruby 1.9. (RuntimeError)
```

As this doesn't occur locally - I'm led to believe it has something to do with Chef and how I'm setting up Ruby on the host

I've also tried installing rvm , purging system ruby and have confirmed the default (global and local) as > 2.0 - none of this has made a difference yet.

I noticed in /usr/local/bin/puma the declaration is

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby1.9.1
```

I edited this to just be ruby - then restarted the service but no change. Is there a way I can force Puma to run under ruby +>2.0 ?

```
ruby_build_ruby '2.0.0-p576'

link "/usr/bin/ruby" do
  to "/usr/local/ruby/2.0.0-p576/bin/ruby"
end



gem_package 'bundler' do
  options '--no-ri --no-rdoc'
end

include_recipe "runit"

deploy_revision("/opt/deploy") do
  revision "develop"
  repository "removed" 
  user "root"
  action :deploy
  shallow_clone true
  keep_releases 3
  rollback_on_error true  # remove release if callbacks failed
  migrate true
  migration_command "rake db:migrate"
  before_migrate do
    execute "bundle install" do
      command "bundle install"
      cwd  "#{release_path}"
      user "root" 
    end
  end
  #restart_command "rails server -b 0.0.0.0"
  # disable default behavior
  symlink_before_migrate.clear
  create_dirs_before_symlink.clear
  purge_before_symlink.clear
  symlinks.clear
end
```

Ubuntu 14.04 , Bundler 1.10.6

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the ruby you've installed is the default for the system (or at least, not when Chef executes bundler). I'm basing that on `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-3.5.3` which seems to indicate you've installed the gem under 1.9.1 as well.

I don't know if you have a preference for rvm or rbenv, but each has a popular community cookbook that can set the default system ruby to the one you want to use, or even just for a particular user (since you're using root, I'd say just set the system ruby as the one you want).

If you were using [the rbenv cookbook](https://github.com/chef-rbenv/ruby_rbenv), it would look like this:

```
include_recipe 'ruby_build'
include_recipe 'ruby_rbenv'
rbenv_global '2.0.0p576'
```

You would also be able to omit these resources you were using before:

```
ruby_build_ruby '2.0.0-p576'
link "/usr/bin/ruby" do
  to "/usr/local/ruby/2.0.0-p576/bin/ruby"
end
```

Also, I'd recommend running as another user than root, so you can only break that user's default ruby instead of the entire system's ruby. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Martin - took me a few days of trying this. In the end it appears to be a difference between using the chef resource "gem_package" and using a bash resource to install bundler - when I switched to bundler via bash things came good.